# Supervised classification with different row length dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I need to make some predictions based on some situations: the problem is how to enconde situations themself. A row in the dataset will represent a single situation but here it comes the problem.

A situation in my case is composed of various objects of 2-3 different kinds: each kind of them has specific set of features, so my situation could be any size long.

For example, let's suppose I have 3 classes of object, A, B, C:
-Objects of class A have 3 features
-Objects of class B have 5 features
-Objects of class C have 2 features
My situation is made of objects of various classes, without any hint  on the number (but I have an empirical maximum, such that class A can have no more than five objects per situation, class B at most 10 and so on).
It could be that a situation has 3 objects of class A, 5 of class B and 4 of class C, but the very next situation has 4 objects of class A and three objects of class B.
What I have to predict is a parameter about each object of class B (suppose), so I replicate each row adding a feature at the end that tells the object under exam (of course I have specific target for each job). Anyway I think it's not very important what I have to predict (I can study it later, but correct me if I am wrong)

The first thought I had is to define a maximum number of objects for each possible kind and fill the empty fields with Nan (or 0s) to indicate the absence of that object, resulting in a fixed global length. Although this way it should be possible, it's not a "beautiful" approach.

I was thinking about using Multiple Instance Learning, but it doesn't suits well my case (because I have more types of object and even though the "bag" can contain a variable number of instances, all the instances must belong to same instance space, but I have more levels of variability).

Considering that I can generate an infinte amount of data (in theory), would it be better to train more classifiers (a classifier for each possible layout)?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about the goal of the classification as well as the data ? Are these "situations" your classes? The way I understand your post is that the observations of the different classes have different features, is this correct? If not, please clarify this.

Comment: Correct! I'll edit the question to be clearer

Comment: This still remains a bit murky to me: a "situation" is composed of any given combination of objects of classes A through C, each of the classes having different (any common?) features ? Can you please spell out the exact classification you would want to perform?   
To me it seems that the entities you want to make predictions for ("situations") are poorly described by the current data. It would be reasonable to first consider how to encapsulate the information you have for a situation in the form  of (a) [random variable(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) first.

Comment: This is all the info I got and it is enough to make decisions for sure: the same data are used by an external tool that, knowing how to handle them, does many things and I just want to extrapolate some basic info.
Entities are described in just that way, but if they are poorly described as you said in the end I won't be able to predict anything, but that's another story (and it could be possible, of course).
I think the point is how to encode them, but I don't understand your hint about r.v.

Comment: "Anyway I think it's not very important what I have to predict (I can study it later, but correct me if I am wrong)". This is the most important thing to consider when approaching such problems. If you are not clear on what you want to predict, how can you assess if the information you use is sufficient to do so?

Comment: You're right of course, but I said that badly: I know the info I got should be enough to predict what I want, so the prediction problem should come after I know how to encode the info.

Comment: If every object has different features then they are not really comparable, so it does not make sense to combine them. Building separate models may be a better choice.

Comment: But it's not the objects per se that I have to compare, it's the situation. Separate models could work if I build one for each possible combination, but I would have so many of them